# getting image path while saving an image in android

Tags: android

I am using the below code for saving an image to SD Card.
But how to get the Image path of the saved image as I wanted to use this path to set Image for a ImageView in next activity.
I tried on with using  `onActivityResult()` but could not get the path.
As `onActivitySesult()`only fires if we want to open a intent to browse file, but I want to access without opening gallery or intent to get the file path. 
Any points would be helpful.
Looking forward to your reply.
thanks.

```
PictureCallback myPictureCallback_JPG = new PictureCallback(){

            @Override
            public void onPictureTaken(byte[] arg0, Camera arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                 FileOutputStream outStream = null;
                  try {
                    // Write to SD Card
                    outStream = new FileOutputStream(String.format("/sdcard/%d.jpg",System.currentTimeMillis())); 
                    outStream.write(arg0);
                    outStream.close();
                    sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED,Uri.parse("file://"+ Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
                    Toast.makeText(Photo.this, "Image Saved to SD Card", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   System.out.println();
                  } catch (FileNotFoundException e) { 
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    //Log.e("Photo", "Image files get saved in SD Card only",e);
                  } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                  }

                camera.startPreview();
            }};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way :

**Assign System.currentTimeMillis() to String or long and pass that to the File Outputstream.**

```
    try {
        String stored_date=System.currentTimeMillis()+"";
        outStream = new FileOutputStream(String.format("/sdcard/%d.jpg",stored_date)); 
        outStream.write(arg0);
        outStream.close();
        sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED,Uri.parse("file://"+ Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
        Toast.makeText(Photo.this, "Image Saved to SD Card", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       System.out.println();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
    catch (IOException e) {}
```

Comment: I did try and it worked, saved the stored_date in shared preference and in another activity I picked up the Image stored_date from shared preference and through setImageUri 'imageAttachPhoto.setImageURI(Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/"+filename+".jpg"));'
thanks.

Comment: any help on how to know whether an ImageView has Image set or not, if Image has been set then I have to access that Image. thanks.